# CMFCButton compilation error

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

I want to use a CMFCButton. When I compile, I get this error:

```
afxbutton.h(183): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'SelectFont'
afxbutton.h(183): error C2226: syntax error: unexpected type 'HFONT'
```

It seems to be in conflict with a windows macro:
[Windows SelectFont() Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectFont is defined in Windowsx.h. To resolve the conflict, find any #include for Windowsx.h in your project and move it after the #include for the MFC controls. Maybe to the end of your stdafx.h.

The same problem can be seen [here](http://www.bcgsoft.com/cgi-bin/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=1125) (note BCGSoft is the company that created the MFC controls, so the same situation applies)

Comment: Weird, they should have tested that code with `Windowsx.h` included. Has someone filed a bug report? Do they have any mechanism for doing so?

Comment: I did not implicitly include the `Windowsx.h` file anywhere, but I moved the the `afxbutton.h` and it worked.